# Constant functor

Tags: category-theory

If there is a given set *S* define a constant functor $ S: Set\to Set $ which takes any set to *S* and any function to $1_S$. Is this really a functor?

I don't understand what type of morphisms defined in the category of Sets. because these are functions. So is that mean a functor S maps $S(f(A))=1_S$ if $f:A\to B$ in the category of sets. How can we prove for $S(1_A) =1_S(A)$ .

Comment: The expression $S(f(A))$ doesn't make sense. Repeat the definitions.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand what you mean by defining any function to identity of S.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $C$ is *any* category and $S \in C$ is *any* object, you can define a constant functor $S : C \to C$ which maps every object to $S$ and every morphism to $1_S$. It is trivial to check that this is, in fact, a functor, since $1_X$ is mapped to $1_S$ and a composition $f \circ g$ is mapped to $1_S = 1_S \circ 1_S$.

Comment: And the object can also be in another category $D$, which defines a constant functor $C\to D$.